# Email Markup doesn't work after whitelisted by Google (17 days already)

Tags: google-schemas

I applied for the Email Markup and on Feb 10, 2020 I received an email from Google Markup team telling that my domain was whitelisted. 
They also specified that it can take up to a week after whitelisting to take effect. 
It's 17 days already and I test my emails dailty, thought neither go-to action button nor Event reservation appears in my email.

Does anybody know if it can take longer then 1 week after whitelisting?
I texted them back but still no response.

Comment: UPD: buttons appeared next day after this post)

Answer (score 0):

It takes at least 3 weeks to start showing on the emails.